Bell like distribution in 3d periodic probability function
In an attempt to set the domain of the Bell / Gauss distribution probability distribution curve as a singly periodic function, (primed derivative wrt $x$ ) modified its ode as
$$ y'=-xy $$ to a periodic one in place of its monotonous behavior with an array pitch is $ 2 \pi$.
I took the new ode as:
$$ y'=-y \sin x $$
Integrating I get a solution with BC $(x-0,y'=0,y_{max}=1)$
$$y= e^{c \cos x}= y_{max}e^{\cos x-1} \tag 1 $$

Its period or wave length is $2 \pi, $ unlike the Bell curve.
Tried to find points of inflection ( motivation is to compare with $\pm \sigma$ points with probability curve)  by setting  the second derivative to zero:
$$\cos^2 x + \cos x -1=0$$
$$ \cos x= (\frac{\sqrt 5 -1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt 5 +1}{2})= (\varphi, -1/\varphi)  $$
Real inflection
$$ x_{I}= \cos^{-1}\varphi \approx 1.061275~ + 2\pi k $$
$$ y_{I}= e^{(\frac{\sqrt 5 -3}{2})}\approx 0.682518$$
where $\varphi$ is the Golden Ratio. This new Bell graph does not plot accurately.
A doubly periodic function can be also defined.

$$ Bell3D(x,y)=e^{\cos x+\cos y-2}$$
3D Bell distribution
Please comment on the above, if such distribution is already known. Hope this would interest you. I did not refer to any text book solutions.

No periodic function except for $0$ can be a probability distribution over $\mathbb{R}$. Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to show?

I imagined a linear sieve with an infinite array of uniformly spaced holes fed by particulate matter like fine sand. Tried to model the same.

I am  trying to  build a connected array of Bell curves composed of unit period distributions, so ode can be further modified to $ a y'=-y \sin(2 \pi x/\lambda).$

@ whpowell96: Edited to include 3D distribution as above. Please comment.

I'm not sure I entirely understand what's going on here, but could you not describe a probability distribution on a torus or something?

Thanks. As a next step it can be described modifying the necessary flat the dimpled surface to a toroidal dimpled surface.

There is no question in your post

No question here but requesting you for comments on this newly formulated extension of domain to a surface for periodically spiked probability distribution and  whether such one is already known etc.
